# T-sql to asp.net Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

```
Select TOP 5 * 
From Kaloriler 
Where KaloriAdi Like '%cikolata%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

What is the equivalent in Entity Framework?

```
.Where(x => x.KaloriAdi.Contains("cikolata"));
```

But how can I use it `COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace: `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`, `public static class SqlFunctions`

Provide you some logic that allows you to converto linq to entities, but in your case, there is no other way than to convert the linq statement into something like this:

```
var sqlRes = db.Database.SqlQuery<ObjectMappingYourSqlResult>
                                ("Select top 5 * 
                                   from Kaloriler 
                                   Where KaloriAdi Like @MyString 
                                   COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI ",
                                  new SqlParameter("MyString ", myValue)
                               ).ToList();
```

Comment: @Ali if this is the correct answer for your question, then please chose it as the correct anwer, and you are also free to give a "vote up" if this was usefull for you.